# $4^{th}$ root of $-6i$

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to find the $4^{th}$ roots of $-6i$.

What I do is:

$$z^4 = -6i$$
$$z^4 = r^4 e^{4i\theta} = 6e^{-i\frac\pi2}$$

$$\implies r=\pm 6^{\frac14}, 4\theta = -\frac\pi2\implies \theta =\frac{-\pi}{8}$$

Then $z=\pm 6^{(\frac14)}e^{\frac{-\pi}{8}i+2\pi n},\quad n\in\Bbb Z$

But apparently not. Where did I go wrong? I would guess when I took $6e^{-i\frac\pi 2}$, but $\frac{3\pi}{2}$ isn't in our 'primary' Arg, $-\pi \leq \theta \leq \pi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, $r=+6^{\frac{1}{4}}$. $r$ is assumed to be positive.

Second, $4\theta=2k\pi-\pi/2$, $k=-1,0,1,2$ if $-\pi \leq \theta \leq \pi$.

Comment: So then I obtain $\theta = \frac{-\pi}{8} + \frac{\pi k}{ 2}, \quad k\in \Bbb Z$. That still has a form $6^{\frac14} e^{-\frac{\pi}{8}i}$ as one of the roots

Comment: $k=-1,0,1,2$, not in $\mathbb{Z}$, since there are only 4 branches.

Comment: Oh yes, 4 roots. But apparently the roots are(for laziness I will just not write $r$ nor $e$, so the powers of $e$ are:

$\frac{3\pi}{8},\frac{7\pi}{8},\frac{11\pi}{8},\frac{15\pi}{8}$

Comment: What's wrong with that as a root?

Comment: Unless $\frac{-\pi}{8}i$ is equivalent to $\frac{15\pi}{8}i$ like in modular arithmetic.(But in my mind they are distance by the difference in radians, but I might just be too tired)

Comment: I see what you meant. Well the angles are equivalent. Since $e^{i\theta}$ only concerns $\theta$ as angles, it is correct. And if you want your angle in $[-\pi,\pi]$, it has to be $-\frac{\pi}{8}i$.

Comment: Oh yes of course, thank you

Comment: What does 'cis' mean? Does it mean Arg?

Comment: I think it means argument, angle, not specifically $Arg$, which means the principle one.

Comment: Okay thanks again

Answer (score 1):

There are four such roots. To find them, you just write

$$-6i =6e^{i(\pi/2 +2\pi k)}$$ so the roots can be any of the values

$$6^{1/4}e^{i(\pi/2 +2\pi k)/4}=6^{1/4}e^{i(\pi/8 +\pi k/2)}$$
Note that every 4th value is the same since $e^{i(\pi k/2)}=e^{i(\pi (k+4)/2)}=e^{i(\pi k/2)}e^{2\pi i}$.